# Is there a difference in Keras between CNN multichannel input feed and 1 channel image sequence feed?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet, channel

Say we want to use tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(args) and feed it a Raw grayscale image of (nxn pixels) and k number of different images resulting from Raw image + different pre-processing techniques of same (nxn) dimensions.

Would it be the same thing to add the new pre-processed images in different input channels for the image and feed a k+1 channel image to the Network as feeding the 1 channel images one by one in a sequence?

1. variant

input : ch1 = raw, ch2 = pre-proc_raw_1, ch3 = pre-proc_raw_2

2. variant

input : 1 channel & sequence of (raw, pre-proc_raw_1, pre-proc_raw_2)

Are the 2 variants equivalent?